# Initializing values for a struct within a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have the following code in the private section of a basic Polynomial class .h file:

```
private:
struct Term
{
    float coefficient;
    int power; // power of specific term
};
int degree; //total number of terms
```

I have the following default constructor for the Polynomial class:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    Polynomial.Term poly;
    poly.power = 0;
    poly.coefficient = 0;
    degree = 1;
}
```

I am confused on how to access the terms inside the struct as well as the variable outside the struct. I tried to google this, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Edit: overloaded output operator code

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & outs, Polynomial & P)
{
    outs << P[0].poly.coefficient << "x^" << P[0].poly.power;
    for (int i=1; i<P.degree-1; i++)
    {
        if (P[i].poly.coefficient > 0)
            outs << "+";
        outs << P[i].poly.coefficient << "x^" << P[i].poly.power;
    }
    outs << endl;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the `poly.` from?

Comment: that is a variable I initialized using Term, trying to access the variables in Term.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: The rest of the code isn't really relevant. I am just trying to figure out how to access the terms in the Term struct in the default constructor. What code are you asking for?

Comment: `Polynomial.Term` Did this really compile?

Answer (score 5):

You've declared the variable within the constructor function.
Once execution leaves the constructor, that variable is destroyed.
Instead, you need to add the variable to the class declaration.
If you want to be able to access the members from outside any of the class functions, you'll also need to make the variables and struct definition public.

```
class Polynomial
{
public:
   struct Term
   {
      float coefficient;
      int power; // power of specific term
   };
   Term poly;
   int degree; //total number of terms

   Polynomial();
};

Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    poly.power = 0;
    poly.coefficient = 0;
    degree = 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Now when overloading the output operator, I'm having trouble accessing power and coefficient. code updated in post

Comment: @JulieRosen - That sounds like a different problem. You should post a new question about that.

Comment: @JulieRosen Yeah, that's a different issue, but as a quick hint: Your "P" variable in that function isn't an array. It looks like what you want is for the "poly" variable to be an array. e.g. `Term poly[100];`
Then you need to index 'poly', e.g. `P.poly[i]`

Comment: Bonus tip, an "std::vector<Term>" is probably more appropriate for this data, rather than using "degree".